# Triggers as Constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables -

```
Create Table "User" (Name, DateofBirth, CategoryId(FK))

Create Table Category(CategoryId(PK), MinimumAge)
```

Each user has a cateogry assigned to them. I am trying to create a rule/trigger contraint 
that enforces that the person holding the category must of minimum age for that category,

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Great idea! School work?

Comment: Sounds like you already know what you need to do. My suggestion would be to do exactly what you said, create a rule on INSERT and UPDATE on the User table that checks the incoming values and validates them accordingly.  

Although, in a lot of cases this kind of validation logic is contained on the front-end.  It's usually faster then sending all of your data to the DB, having it validate, gathering the results, returning any found issues and then alerting the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that uses a user defined function to lookup the age range/minimum based on their category

The UDF should return 1 or 0 based on the pass/fail of the logic

For example

```
check (dbo.IsAboveMinAge(dob, categoryId) = 1)
```

where the `IsAboveMinAge` calculates the current age based on the passed dob and compares against the `SELECT MinimumAge FROM Category where CategoryID = categoryId` returned value)